# Suggestions needed to debug why ps -ef gets stuck

Tags: linux, kernel

Issue beginning - Few of my PID consume 100% cpu, I want to understand which script is executing that PID command.

My debugging steps:

strace ps -ef

open("/proc/PID/status", O_RDONLY) = 6
read(6, "Name:\textract\nState:\tR (running)"..., 1023) = 1023
close(6) = 0
open("/proc/PID/cmdline", O_RDONLY) = 6
read(6,

So it gets stuck trying to open /proc/PID/cmdline

I tried catting that, it got stuck again

Something is obviously screwed in the kernel, please let me know your suggestions or next debugging steps

Notes: shutdown doesn't work, if I shutdown manually the problem starts again.

ps: Because of my reputation, I am unable to chat. Please feel free to ask output of any suggested commands, I will paste it ASAP!

Comment: Does iotop give any unusual pointers?

Comment: I don't have iotop.

Comment: Is this a real server or a OpenVZ / Virtuozzo container?

Comment: Can you install other tools?

Comment: It's a baremetal one

Comment: @Ross, may be I can but I have to get some permissions. So I will stick to the word that I won't be able to install new tools

Comment: [Cross-posted at Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10980) — [don't do that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068). Choose one site and stick to it (if you regret your choice, flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it).

Answer (score 0):

If your system has a root kit, the `ps` or even `/proc` could be corrupted due to a bug in the root kit.  I'm not real sure how you get out from under a root kit without a reinstall.